# Static Library in windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create a static library kind of stuff which has to be used in all our wp7 apps. In iPhone app, we can create static library and that library can be integrated in to any iPhone application and then we can use all the classes and methods which are there in the static library with in the application in which we have integrated the static library.

How do we achieve the same thing in windows phone 7? or What is the wp7 equivalent to iPhone static library?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a **windows phone class library** project and **add refrence** to it on your **WP7 App**.

The above **class library** project then can be used in other **WP7 Apps**.

Comment: I have to create an App class (App.xaml.cs and App.xaml) in the class library and the application's App class needs to be derived from the class libary's App class. Can you tell me how this can be done?

Comment: @saikamesh: You should be able to add App.xml and App.xml.cs in the WP7 class library project. Then derive your main App class from the class in the library project.

Comment: I have created App.xaml and App.xaml.cs in my class library, it compiles with no error. Now I need to add my class library as a reference into my application. How do I do this.(means which file I need to integrate)